# Port-based messaging between content script and popup doesn't work by default

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to change the dom element by click on chrome extension

my files are

```js
popup.html
popup.js
myScript.js
manifest.json
```

When user clicks on extension icon then popup opens with a button. IF user clicks on that button then in the DOM if user drags the mouse on any elements i want add border to that element.

popup.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: "Segoe UI", "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, sans-serif;
        font-size: 100%;
      }
      .wrapper{
        /* avoid an excessively wide status text */
        white-space: pre;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
        min-width: 400px;
        min-height: 100px;
      }
      .action{
        display: -webkit-flex;
        flex-direction:row;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items:center;
      }
      .btn{
        width: 100px;
        height: 35px;
        border-top-left-radius: 26px;
        border-top-right-radius: 26px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 26px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 26px;
        border: 3px solid gray;
        color: #CA3F39;
        font-weight: 500;
        background: white;
        cursor: pointer;
        outline: none;
      }
      .btn.end,.btn.download{
        display: none;
      }
    </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="action buttons">
          <button class="btn make" id="makeTour">Start</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```js
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port){
    $('#start').on('click',function(e){
      port.postMessage( { start : true } );
    });
});
```

myScript.js

```js
var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name:"start"});
port.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender){
    if(message.start){
        $(document).on('mousemove',function(e){
           $(e.target).css('border','1px solid green');
        })
    }
});
```

manifest.json

```js
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "asd",
  "description": "This extension shows a Google Image search result for the current page",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background.scripts":{
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts":[
    { 
      "matches": [ "http://*/*","https://*/*"],
      "js":["jquery.js","myScript.js"],
      "css": [ "buttons.css" ] 
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources":[
    "favicon.png","default.gif","ic_clear.png","popup.js"
  ],
  "permissions":[
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "content_security_policy":"script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://www.google.com; object-src 'self' "
}
```

This code is working if I open popup.html and inspect in developer tools on popup.html by clicking on extension icon.

If I close that developer tools of that popup.html file mouse move is not working.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. Including a **manifest.json**, some of the background/content/popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: added a manifest.json

Comment: You need to initiate communication in the popup. Currently when your content script runs the popup is closed meaning it doesn't exist.

Comment: I would suggest that you read the [Chrome extension overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) (and perhaps along with the pages linked from the overview). The [architecture section](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally organized/done. You will probably also want to read [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), and [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Comment: *Please* don't load jQuery into **every** page (`content_scripts` with your `matches`) unless you **need** to.  jQuery is 85kiB of minimized code. This is a significant burden with which to saddle *every single page*. What of those of us who have 100's of tabs open? While It is possible you really *need* to load jQuery, it is more likely that you are doing so for the convenience of saving a couple/few hundred characters in your own code by not using vanilla JavaScript. If that is the case (as is shown in the code above), doing so is a *very* poor trade-off from your user's point of view.

Comment: You are assuming the popup script is always running. It is only active when the popup is being shown. If the popup is not being shown, then the popup code does not exist. You should look into background pages.